# How do I point to this piece of memory correctly to treat it as my struct?

Tags: c

I have the following code. The file contains a bitmap image were the first bytes are 0x424d. I would expect the first printf to print BM, instead it prints BM??.

Additionally, the second printf prints 10, and I would expect it to be a larger number since the file is larger then 10 bytes.

```
fp = fopen("input.bmp", "r");
bmp_header_p = malloc(sizeof(bmp_header_t));

rewind(fp);
fread(bmp_header_p, sizeof(char), 14, fp);

printf("magic number = %s\n", bmp_header_p->magic);
printf("file size = %" PRIu32 "\n", bmp_header_p->filesz);

typedef struct {
uint8_t magic[2];   /* the magic number used to identify the BMP file:
                     0x42 0x4D (Hex code points for B and M).
                     The following entries are possible:
                     BM - Windows 3.1x, 95, NT, ... etc
                     BA - OS/2 Bitmap Array
                     CI - OS/2 Color Icon
                     CP - OS/2 Color Pointer
                     IC - OS/2 Icon
                     PT - OS/2 Pointer. */
uint32_t filesz;    /* the size of the BMP file in bytes */
                     of the byte where the bitmap data can be found. */
} bmp_header_t;
```

Comment: The `%s` conversion expects a pointer to the first element of a 0-terminated `char` array. You don't pass it one.

Comment: You need to open your file in binary mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%s` is for null-terminated strings. `magic` is just an array of 2 bytes, not a string.

```
printf("magic number = %c%c\n", bmp_header_p->magic[0], bmp_header_p->magic[1]);
```

Comment: I see. Any idea on the filesz?

Comment: What is the expected filesz?

Comment: Files should be the size of the BMP file. 703K input.bmp

Comment: Structure alignment and big/little-endedness are the most likely culprits.

Comment: Since most common processors are little-endian these days, I didn't think endianness was likely to be the culprit. But you're probably right about alignment.

Answer (score 2):

You have several problems:

1. The compiler is likely adding padding into your data structure between the `magic` and `filesz` members.  There are compiler-specific extensions such as pragmas and attributes you can use to avoid this behavior and get packed structures ([Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Type-Attributes.html)).  But these are not portable and should be avoided if possible.
2. The `%s` format specifier expects a null-terminated string, but the string you're passing is not terminated.  You should instead use a specifier such as `%.2s` to print at most 2 characters.
3. The bitmap file format is little-endian.  If your computer is also little-endian, then it will appear to work correctly, but when you compile for a big-endian architecture, you'll find it will suddenly stop working.  You must endian-swap any multibyte values like `filesz` on big-endian platforms.
4. The call to `rewind(3)` is not necessary—the file pointer is guaranteed to be at the start of the file after you open it.

There are many ways to solve problem (1); there are countless articles and answers about how to do serialization correctly in C.  I'd recommend just reading each member individually so that you don't have to worry about how the compiler lays out your structure, and it will be fully portable to all platforms.

Also, `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1 by the C standard, so there's rarely a need to explicitly write out `sizeof(char)` in e.g. function arguments to `fread(3)`.

Answer (score 1):

When you print something as a string, the `printf` function will keep going until it reaches a null terminator.  So although the first two bytes might represent `BM`, you did nothing to ensure that printing stops there. Unless the next byte in memory is `'0'` the `printf` will keep looking for characters and printing them. It turns out that the next two are "unprintable", and result in `??`. After that, there might be a `'0'` so output stops...

As for the second point - the format specification says that the integers are stored in little-endian format. You are doing nothing to make sure you are interpreting the number that way - it's possible that you are in fact working with a big-endian machine, in which case the number `10` is really 10*256*256*256 = 167772160.  Of course there is no guarantee that numbers in a structure are actually aligned how you think - it's possible that there is some (compiler, platform) specific padding going on. And then there's the question of what happens when a binary file is opened in "r" rather than "rb" mode...

Here is a possible way to tackle these things:

```
#define HEADER_SIZE 14
#define SIZE_START 2

fp = fopen("input.bmp", "r");
bmp_header_p = malloc(HEADER_SIZE);

fread(bmp_header_p, HEADER_SIZE, 1, fp);

printf("magic number = %c%c\n", bmp_header_p[0], bmp_header_p[1]);

long int fileSize=0, ii;
for(ii=0;ii<4;ii++) fileSize+=256*fileSize + bmp_header+p[ii + SIZE_START];

printf("file size = %ld\n", fileSize);
```

Answer (score 0):

just fill a 3 char null terminated array.

`char label[] ="00\0";
   label[0] =magic[0];
   label[1] =magic[1];
   prints("%s\n", label );`